# Beanstalk .ebextensions Error - Unresolved resource dependencies in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

What I want to do - is to add ALB ListenerRule only if Beanstalk Environment Name is either "prod" or "prod-2". If Beanstalk Environment Name differs, I what it to skip this resource and proceed without creating it.

Here is my .ebextensions/00-testing-condition.config :

```
"Conditions" : {
    "createRedirect" : {"Fn::Or" : [ {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "prod"]}, {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "prod-2"]} ]}
  }

Resources:
    ALBListenerSSLRule:
        Condition: createRedirect
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
        Properties:
          Actions:
            - RedirectConfig:
                Host: "#{host}"
                Path: "/#{path}"
                Port: 443
                Protocol: "HTTPS"
                Query: "#{query}"
                StatusCode: HTTP_301
              Type: "redirect"
          Conditions:
          - Field: host-header
            Values:
            - "MYDOMAINNAME.com"
          ListenerArn:
              Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener
          Priority: 1
```

As a result: ListenerRule is created if the env name is prod or prod-2 without any issues. However, if the name differs (so the statement is false), I receive the following error in Beanstalk:

`Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ALBListenerSSLRule] in the Resources block of the template`

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Conditions do not work in Beanstalk as expected. 
Therefore, I ended up setting up domain names and redirects for every env and adding this resource using Environment Property (variable) in Beanstalk:

```
Resources:
    ALBListenerSSLRule:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
        Properties:
          Actions:
            - RedirectConfig:
                Host: "#{host}"
                Path: "/#{path}"
                Port: 443
                Protocol: "HTTPS"
                Query: "#{query}"
                StatusCode: HTTP_301
              Type: "redirect"
          Conditions:
          - Field: host-header
            Values:
            - "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
                  Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
                  OptionName: "ENV_DOMAIN_NAME"
                  DefaultValue: {"Ref":"AWS::NoValue"}
          ListenerArn:
              Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener
          Priority: 1
```